# Table of Contents numbering issues

Tags: table-of-contents

[image: TOC]

Hello everyone,

I have no idea why the numbers in each of the sections show as 0.1,0.2 ...etc. I have tried to fix the code but couldn't. Your help and suggestion are greatly appreciated. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}%For type of paper
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{setspace}% For double space
\doublespacing% For double space
\usepackage{subeqnarray} % For number equations (1a), (1b) etc.
\usepackage{graphicx,epstopdf} % For including graphics
\usepackage[framed , numbered]{matlab-prettifier}% For MATLAB code
\usepackage{amssymb}% ams math, symbol packages
\usepackage{amsmath} % more ams
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------
\title{\textbf{Fourier Series and Gibbs Phenomenon with An Application in MATLAB} }
\author{Author: Waleed Al Ikhwan\\[0.5cm]{ Professor: Fernando Charro}}
\affil{Department of Mathematics}
\affil{Wayne State University}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\doublespacing
\section{Abstract}
\section{introduction}
\section{Motivation}
\section{Analysis}
\subsection{Convergance of Fourier Series}
\subsection{Dirichlet Kernel}
\section{Results}
\section{Conclusion}
```

Comment: The highest sectioning level in the `report` class is `\chapter`. If you only use `\section` and levels below that you implicitly work in chapter 0. Either use `\chapter` as the highest sectioning level (i.e. move all levels up one step) or switch to a class without chapters (`article` doesn't have chapters).

Answer (score 2):

You are using the `report` class and so you are supposed to have your text divided into chapters. Since you have introduced no chapter, LaTeX assumes that everything is taking place in chapter 0. Hence the 0.